# Is there an analog for the "derivative as a function" in multiple variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, partial-derivative, differential-forms

- Given the plane curve $y=f(x)=\cos(x)$, the function $f'(x)=-\sin(x)$ models the slope of the tangent line to $f$ at each point.
- Given the surface $z=f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, the functions $z_x=2x$ and $z_y=2y$ model the slopes of the tangent lines to the $x$ and $y$ curve-slices of $f$ at each point.

But neither $z_x$ nor $z_y$ are the analogous "[derivative of $f$ as a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Derivative_as_a_function)." That is, neither models the slope of the tangent *plane* to the surface $f$ at every point--like the effect of the single variable derivative.

My question: is there a function which models the slope of the tangent plane to a surface at every point?

My guess: The differential does give us the whole picture as far as rate of change in each coordinate direction: $dz=2xdx+2ydy$. But $dz$ is a differential 1-form i.e. a covector field. If my guess is correct, that $dz$ is the analogous "derivative of $f$ as a function," does it have a graph? Can $dz$ be realized as a surface?

In the loosest of phrasing, similar to how the derivative of a curve is a curve, is the derivative of a surface a surface?

Comment: The tangent plane is characterized by a vector of slopes in each direction. So the derivative is a mapping with the range now being vectors instead of scalars. You put in a point, and you get out the gradient at the point, which completely characterizes the tangent plane

Comment: Have you ever heard the term "Fréchet derivative"?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the first comment. I'm still not sure what exactly you're saying is the function that models the slope of the tangent plane to a surface at every point. What are we plugging into and why does it give the gradient at that point? Isn't the differential essentially the coordinate-independent gradient?

Comment: Yes, the gradient is essentially the same thing as the differential. Either way, it's two functions of two variables. The graph of such a function is a surface in $4$-dimensional space, namely, $$ \{ (x,y,f_x(x,y), f_y(x,y) \} \subset \mathbb{R}^4.$$ This unfortunately is hard to visualize.

Comment: @ElijahR You can ask the question: if I walk along the tangent plane in direction $v$, how much will I go up/down? The answer is $g \cdot v$, where $g$ is the gradient and $\cdot$ is the dot product. Or $dz(v)$ if you like to think of the differential as a linear functional. Now this holds for every $v$, so it completely characterizes the tangent plane.